# How do I highlight specific pixels in an image using masking?

Tags: google-earth-engine, digital-image-processing

The two images below are the same.

In the images, the value of each pixel corresponds to a date in milliseconds.

[image]

In the top image, the pixels with the higher values - more recent date - are highlighted, while those with lower values are less highlighted.

The bottom image represents the raw mask of the image.

I imagine it is something to do with the masking of the image, but I am still figuring out what processing or operation was done to get this result.

Any ideas?

Code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/27a90e3abd360f7334ea41d0a4a9a9f6

Comment: What do you mean by highlight? Do you want a different color palette with classified pixels, where newest pixels are class, say, 3, the next oldest class is 2, and the oldest is 1?

Comment: Can you notice in the (smoothed) image that there is processing that makes some pixels look like dust? The lower the pixel value, the less apparent it is.

As I said, I think it is something related to the masking of the image. In this case, the values should range from 0 to 1.

Comment: Do you want just a binary mask where either a pixel is visible or it’s not?

Comment: No. I think the solution would not be a binary mask (0 or 1) but a mask with intermediate values.

Comment: The values do range from 0 - 1. The faint pixels have values closer to 0. If you click over to the Inspector tab on right side of map, you can see values of pixels you click on.

Comment: I noticed this as well. I tried normalizing the pixel values in the range 0-1 (using the `clamp()` function) and updated the image mask but did not get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that you tried `clamp()`, I'm assuming that you want the values reclassified.

```
var alerts = ee.ImageCollection('projects/radar-wur/raddalert/v1');
var geography = 'sa';

var latestAlert = ee.Image(
  alerts
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('layer', 'alerts'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('geography', geography))
    .sort('system:time_end', false)
    .first());

var confirmedAlertMask = latestAlert.select('Alert').eq(3);

var timeStart = ee.Date(latestAlert.get('system:time_start'));
var timeEnd = ee.Date(latestAlert.get('system:time_end'));
var differenceInDays = timeEnd.difference(timeStart, 'day');

// YYDOY (Year-Year-Day-of-Year).
var from = ee.List.sequence(0, differenceInDays).map(function(d) {
  return ee.Number.parse(
    timeStart.advance(d, 'day').format('yyDDD'))
    .subtract(1);
});

// Milliseconds.
var to = ee.List.sequence(0, differenceInDays)
  .map(function(d) {
    return timeStart.advance(d, 'day').millis();
  });

var alertInMillis = latestAlert
  .select('Date')
  // .updateMask(confirmedAlertMask)
  .remap(from, to)
  .rename('alertDate');

// Classifying, or reclassing the values.
var classValues = [0, 1, 2, 3];
var remapValues = ee.List.sequence({start:0, end:1, count:4});
var remapVal = ee.List.sequence({start: 0, end:1, count:3});
var label = 'lc';
var latestRmap = latestAlert.remap(classValues, remapValues).rename(label).toByte();

print(latestRmap, 'remap')

// Iago's original maps, alert in milliseconds
Map.addLayer(alertInMillis.updateMask(confirmedAlertMask.mask()), {}, 'Millis mask Raw');
Map.addLayer(alertInMillis.mask(), {}, 'Millis mask Smoothed');

// Iago's maps without ".mask()"
Map.addLayer(alertInMillis.updateMask(confirmedAlertMask), {}, 'Millis Raw');
Map.addLayer(alertInMillis, {}, 'Millis Smoothed');

// Alert in days, without a mask
Map.addLayer(latestAlert.updateMask(confirmedAlertMask), {}, 'No Mask Raw');
Map.addLayer(latestAlert, {}, 'No Mask Smoothed');

// Alert in days, with a mask
Map.addLayer(latestAlert.updateMask(confirmedAlertMask).mask(), {}, 'Mask Raw');
Map.addLayer(latestAlert.mask(), {}, 'Mask Smoothed');

// Original data, same as Alert in days without mask
Map.addLayer(latestAlert, {}, 'latest')

// Original data reclassed
Map.addLayer(latestRmap, {}, 'lc')
Map.setCenter(-65.81, -9.198, 8);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5245cc7b6205254f99f3e888b785659c